# How can i customize UIDatePicker for Hijri

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

How can i customize UIDatePicker for Hijri?
Like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ViewController`, adopt the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol, and add a `UIPickerView` to the view, setting its delegate and datasource to `self`.

Override the `pickerView:widthForComponent:` method from `UIPickerViewDelegate` to have a custom width for each component (a component is a "column", so here you have three)

Override the `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` from the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol an return 3

To populate your picker, use `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` from `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` from `UIPickerViewDataSource`

For a cleaner and more reusable code, I'll just subclass `UIPickerView`